# How to write a compareTo method when comparing multiple variables at once?

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I have an assignment where I have an object with 3 String variables (title, author, date). I need to implement Comparable (which I have done), then write a compareTo method, and then write a method match(String query) where it uses the compareTo method to check if the title, author or date contains the query.

I'm confused because my understanding of compareTo is taking a variable and comparing its value between two instances of the object, but in my case I don't want to compare two object instances together and I'm looking at more than one variable.

**Edit:** Thank you all for the answers, it turned out the compareTo was only to display the match results in alphabetical order.

I had been confused as when asking in the class forum about comparing the query in the match method, his response had been to implement Comparable and write compareTo. I'm still not sure why he said that, but after using it for alphabetizing the resulting matches only, the output works and matches his example demo.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `compareTo` to implement `match`, as you describe `match` as checking whether the author *contains* the query string, not that the author *equals* the query string. That is, an author "Forester" would match a query of "Forest".

Comment: So, a "object" may have multiple properties, which some or all might be used to produce a "comparison" to another instance of the same object.  I'd argue that using `Comparable` to "match" two objects probably isn't the right approach and would argue that `equals` would be a better choice, but, there is a educational aspect to the requirement, so we can let that slip

Comment: I was also confused about that, but an example output the lecturer has given uses the query "194" to return all the objects with the date in the 1940s (of which there were 5, and they all were of different years.

The exact wording of the brief is as follows: "Implement the match method to return true if the input query is contained in 
either the title or publisher or release date. The query is not case sensitive. 
Implement the Comparable interface to compare titles."

Comment: @RachelC There is a difference between what `compareTo` is to do and what `match(String)` should do, both will compare the properties of the object, but `compareTo` is comparing it to another instance of the object, where as `match` is comparing each property to the string (in some way)

Comment: a Comparable is about establishing an **order** between objects (42 is after 17 but before 99), so it's unclear what that has to do with deciding "if the title, author or date contains the query".

Comment: Oh, per the comment, the Comaprable interface (compareGo) is only for comparing titles. It sounds like a case-blind string comparison is all that is needed for that.  The "match" methos is entirely separate.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right, so my initial try was to make the match method the one to return true if the query matches the title, author, or date, but then I was at a loss to what to include in the compareTo? I don't see how comparing two of the objects is relevant, but I still have to somehow do it as it is what the assignment requires.

Comment: @user16632363 hmm, I wonder if the compareTo then is only needed so the list of matches returned to the output is in alphabetical order by title... in his demo to test our code it does have a bit that says Collections.sort(matches).

Comment: The implementation of `match` and `compareTo` are completely separate issues, from what you have said. Comparing two objects is not relevant to the query, just to (e.g.) sorting objects.

Comment: @RachelC *"but then I was at a loss to what to include in the compareTo? I don't see how comparing two of the objects is relevant, but I still have to somehow do it as it is what the assignment requires"* - Without more details about the requirements, it's difficult to provide an accurate answer, other then to say, the intention of `Comparable` is to allow you to "order" a series/list of objects in "natural" order, based on the requirements of the object.  Matches is, however, comparing the contents of each property against a single query

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have an method to convert query to album and then use compareTo method. Adjust the convert method to match your requirement.

Here is pseudo code.

```
Album{
    String title;
    String author;
    Date date;
    ... getter and setter method
    
    public boolean match(String query){
        Album album = convertToAlbum(query);
        return compareTo(album) == 0;
    }

    private Album convertToAlbum(String query){
        Album album = new Album();
        String[] arrs = query.split(";");
        album.setTitle(arrs[0]);
        album.setAuthor(arrs[1]);
        album.setDate(parseDate(arrs[2]));
        return album;
    }

    public int compareTo(Album album){
       // your implement code.
    }
}
```

In case you don't want to use compareTo, just don't use it.

```
public boolean match(String query){
            return title.contains(query) || author.contains(query) ...;
        }
```

Comment: That's not what the question asks. "check if the title, author or date contains the query"

Comment: It's also not pseudo code.  Looks like Java to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `Comparable#compareTo` and `match(String)` and what they are trying to achieve.

`Comparable` defines a means to order a series of objects based on some kind of pre-defined algorithm for the object.

`match(String)` is trying to determine if one or more of the properties "matches" the defined `String`

Without any more information on the requirements, `compareTo` might look something like ...

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Book other) {
    return getTitle().compareTo(other.getTitle();
}
```

Where as `matches` needs to compare the values of each property against the supplied value, something like...

```
public boolean matches(String query) {
    return getTitle().contains(query) ||
            getAuthor().contains(query) ||
            getDate().contains(query);
}
```

*nb: I'm assuming all the object properties are `String`*

*nbb: This is also doing a case sensitive comparison, again "requirements"*

Comment: One of the comments posted by the OP says "Implement the Comparable interface to compare titles." so I'd interpret that as meaning "compare titles only".  I'm not saying it makes sense...

Comment: @user16632363 Ah, thanks, I've been trying to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

The match method for a single obect is like

```
  boolean match(String query) {
      return title.contains(query) || 
             author.contains(query) || 
             date.contains(query);
  }
```

You'll need to iterate that over all Albums and return a list of matches.

Meanwhile, the compareTo method is like

```
  int compareTo(Album other) {
      return title.compareToIgnoreCase(other.title);
  }
```

Comment: According to the question, the date is a String too.

Comment: I'd also be very careful with using `Date#toString` as this will give different results on systems with different time stamps, just saying

Comment: Right, but this is clearly an introductory programming exercise, not production stuff.  First step is figuring out how to compare things at all!

Comment: @tgdavies oh, you're right - the data is just a String. I got the 'Date' from another answer. I'll fix that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not going to jump and down about (too much ;)), but we should "try" where ever we can to demonstrate "good practices", especially to learners, as they're the ones who will fill the production code of the future with ... interesting ideas ;)

Comment: I'm a bottom-up kind of guy.  First you learn how to do it yourself so you get a feel for how things really work, and then you learn to use the precision tools that someone else  provided.